# Ansible Custom file

Tags: git, awk, devops

Normally I write code in the terminal like that, and I can see the output:

```
git --version | awk '{print $3}' 
2.18.3 (for example)
```

But when I write a custom file like that :

```
#!/bin/bash

git_version=$(git --version | awk '{print $3}')
httpd_version=$(httpd -version | awk 'NR==1 {print $3}')

cat << EOF
{ "Git_version": "$git_version"
  "httpd_version":"$httpd_version"
}
EOF
```

git version can't be seen as git_version variable value. Why?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: The custom script works fine. What is the problem that you are facing ? Is this related to Ansible ? Please update the question with the necessary details

Comment: Yeah works fine, but when I write a custom file in Ansible, git version doesn't seem.

Comment: @theMayer I want to see sometimes httpd and git version in all the servers via ansible.